# Method to map data from two JSON Files

Tags: c#, json, .net

How can I write a method in C# to map products from a JSON file and match the group name by `productId` from a different file? I just want to output the results to look something like this:

```cs
[Name("ProductId")]
public string ProductId { get; set; }

[Name("Date")]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }

[Name("Price")]
public decimal Price { get; set; }

public string Category { get; set; }
public string ProductId { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<QuotesModel> Quotes { get; set; }
```

```json
{
  "Category": "Shoes",
  "AsOfDate": "12/02/2021",
  "Quotes": [
    {
      "ProductId": "Shoe 1",
      "AsOfDate": "12/02/2021",
      "Value": 11481.99
    },
    {
      "ProductId": "Shoe 2",
      "AsOfDate": "12/02/2021",
      "Value": 5534.99
    },
    {
      "ProductId": "Shoe 3",
      "AsOfDate": "12/02/2021",
      "Value": 4753.99
    }]
}
```

My Product JSON data is like this:

```json
[
  {
    "ProductId": "EU9012 Curncy",
    "AsOfDate": "2019-12-31T00:00:00",
    "Value": 4741.99
  },
  {
    "ProductId": "EU2026 Govt",
    "AsOfDate": "2019-12-31T00:00:00",
    "Value": 1432.99
  },
  {
    "ProductId": "EU2020 Curncy",
    "AsOfDate": "2019-12-31T00:00:00",
    "Value": 4356.99
  },
]
```

And my Category JSON looks like:

```json
[
  {
    "GroupName": "Shoes",
    "ProductId": "EUCF101",
    "Quotes": null
  },
  {
    "GroupName": "Tshirts",
    "ProductId": "EUCF1010",
    "Quotes": null
  },
  {
    "GroupName": "Jeans",
    "ProductId": "EUCF1012",
    "Quotes": null
  },
]
```

I need a method to create a single JSON to output quotes for each category based on any `productId` matches.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following model to your project

```cs
public class Rootobject
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string AsOfDate { get; set; }
    public Quote[] Quotes { get; set; }
}

public class Quote
{
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
    public string AsOfDate { get; set; }
    public float Value { get; set; }
}
```

then you could deserialize your JSON file like this

```cs
string jsonString = File.ReadAllText("fileName.tex");
Rootobject rootobject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Rootobject>(jsonString);
```

don't forget, use this name spaces

```
using System.Text.Json;
using System.IO;
```

Read more on [How to serialize and deserialize JSON in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I Have to different json files, one that contain the data for the products, and another one with category and productId. What i need to do is to match the products by the id and display a Json that shows products by each categories